# How to configure custom port in Security List for an instance?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am setting up a new Ubuntu instance in Oracle cloud. I can ssh that instance using public IP and public key after configuring security list for 22 port. I try to do the same for 80 port but it is not working. I can't access that port using public IP.

Did i miss any basic setup?

Answer (score 1):

Opening port 80 in the security list isn't enough: you'll need to open it in ubuntu's firewall also.

```
$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 80 proto tcp
```

Comment: or, if `ufw` isn't there, something like `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 22 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow SSH access on port 22"`